# C# Tcp Client Can not send a message to android server

Tags: java, c#, android

I wrote a server for android. The Server works good and I succeed to send a message from app that simulate a client (SocketTest).
So I wrote a client in C# by my self.
I tried my client against SocketTest(As server of course) and it's work.
The connection step to android seems to be good, I get no exception. 
But I don't see the message in my Android device.

C# code

```
{
public partial class sendSms : Form
{
    TcpClient client;
    NetworkStream ns;
    public sendSms()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Connect()
    {
        client = new TcpClient("192.168.14.76", 8080);
        //client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8080);
        ns = client.GetStream();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connect();
    }

    private void sendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendMessage();

    }

    private void SendMessage()
    {
        string sendMSG =  msgTB.Text;
        ns.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sendMSG), 0, sendMSG.Length);
        ns.Flush();


    }
}
```

}

Andorid Server

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
Handler UiHandler;
Thread thread = null;
private TextView textView;
private static final int PORT = 8080;
private String status = null;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ipTextView);
    UiHandler = new Handler();
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
    textView.setText("Ip - " + ipAddress + ", Port - " + PORT);
    // statusTxt.setText("Hello");

    this.thread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    this.thread.start();

}


class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;

    private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        try {

            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                String read = input.readLine();

                UiHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

public String[] getPhoneAndMSG(String msg)
{
    return  msg.split("&");
}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable
{
    private String msg;

    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            textView.setText(msg);
            String[] numAndMsG = getPhoneAndMSG(msg);
           // SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), numAndMsG[0] +" " +numAndMsG[1] , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // smsManager.sendTextMessage(numAndMsG[0], null, numAndMsG[1], null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Faild", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        // textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

```
string sendMSG = msgTB.Text + "\r\n";
```